# Reverse single linked list using recursion

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

```
struct node{
    int i;
    struct node* link;
};
struct node* head;
void reverse(struct node* prev, struct node* cur){
    if(cur){
        reverse(cur,cur->link);
        cur->link = prev;
    }
    else
        head = prev;
}
void main(){
    reverse(NULL,head);
}
```

In the above code how to insert data(list of numbers as input) into SLL?, so that I come to know about how the elements are being reversed when input is given, by displaying it, and what code should I write in main() to do that?, since it is recursion.

Comment: for (i = 0, list = head; list != NULL; i++, list = list->next) list->i = i;

Comment: Have you created the SLL `create_sll()` ?

Answer (score 1):

With the given declarations, this code would build a small list to use for testing, call the function, and then print the resulting list:

```
int main(void)
{
  struct node a, b, c, d;
  a.i = 1;
  a.link = &b;
  b.i = 2;
  b.link = &c;
  c.i = 3;
  c.link = &d;
  d.i = 4;
  d.link = NULL;

  reverse(NULL, &a);

  for (const struct node *iter = &a; iter != NULL; iter = iter->link)
    printf("%d\n", iter->i);

  return 0;
}
```